# Android Graylog Sidecar Integration

Tags: android, logging, graylog, sidecar

This is the setup:
An Android Smartphone, constantly running an App and sending HTTP Requests to a Spring Boot Application on an Apache Server. The server is using Graylog Sidecar, which ships the Logs to the Graylog Server.

So my question is, is there a way other than sending http-Requests from Android directly to the graylog server?
Maybe even a Sidecar Implementation?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check this ? https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.1/pages/sending_data.html

Comment: That brings me back to writing HTTP-Requests myself and also meaning I have to deal with the possibility of the graylog server being down. I am searching for something out of the box, if there is something.